# Set node-fetch parameter dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-fetch

For a unit test I am creating a new user via POST in my database, retrieving a id and token. After that I want to DELETE this user with the id, token I just received from the first fetch.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

type Response = {
       status: number,
       body: any
};

const response = {} as Response;

someFunction(async () => {

    // Create new user
    await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({email: 'user@test.com', password: 'test-password'}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(res => {
            res.json().then(json => response.body = json);
        }
    );

    // Delete user just created
    await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/' + response.body.id, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + response.body.token
        }
    });
});
```

The first fetch runs successfully `response.body.id` and `response.body.token` are not empty but the second fetch always fails anyways with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

I would appreciate if someone could point out why. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it happens is because you're mixing up some methods. When your first fetch fulfills it will call the first `then()` method. Inside of that you call the `json()` method of the response and chain the promise from there. Now the first `then()` did not get a returned value, so the `fetch` thinks it's finished. But in reality your `res.json()` promise could still be running.

All the while your second `fetch` request is already being called while `res.json()` is still resolving. That's why the value is `undefined`.

So await the first fetch and store the response. Then await the `json()` promise and store the result of that. Now your thread goes through each step without having a race condition.

The values from the JSON response will now be available in your second `fetch` request.

The second `fetch` doesn't have to use `await`. Only if you need the values from the response and need to do something whenever that request finishes.

```
someFunction(async () => {

    // Create new user
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({email: 'user@test.com', password: 'test-password'}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });

    const json = await response.json();

    // Delete user just created
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/' + json.id, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + json.token
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That clears a lot of confusion for me.